# Calculate distance between the center of a point on a scatter plot to the edge of it's marker, for dynamically changing marker sizes in Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, visualization

I have a scatter plot which I'd like to place by another scatter plot, however they have a dynamic marker size.

The green triangles (x, y) are calculated from the original scatter and they're close but not perfect (just from trial and error).

```
import pandas as pd
from mplsoccer import Pitch, VerticalPitch
  
data = [['JA', 35, 60, 2000], ['RN', 20, 47, 1500], ['GG', 10, 32, 1000]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'x', 'y', 'marker_size'])

#This is calculated from x or y length divided by marker size of biggest marker,
# divide by 2 for the radius, but the marker sizes seem to be non-linear.
df['xDiff'] = df['marker_size'] * ((7.3/2000) / 2)
df['yDiff'] = df['marker_size'] * ((11.3/2000) / 2)

df['leftArrowX'] = df['x'] - df['xDiff']
df['leftArrowY'] = df['y']
df['rightArrowX'] = df['x'] + df['xDiff']
df['rightArrowY'] = df['y']

df['downArrowY'] = df['y'] - df['yDiff']
df['downArrowX'] = df['x']
df['upArrowY'] = df['y'] + df['yDiff']
df['upArrowX'] = df['x']

pitch = Pitch(pitch_type='opta', pitch_color='#202428', line_color='#F2F2F2', linewidth=2)
fig, ax = pitch.draw(figsize=(16, 10))

players = pitch.scatter(df.x, df.y, s=df.marker_size, marker='8', color='orange', edgecolors='black', linewidth=1, alpha=1, ax=ax)
leftArrows = pitch.scatter(df.leftArrowX, df.leftArrowY, s=100, marker='<', color='lightgreen', alpha=1, ax=ax)
rightArrows = pitch.scatter(df.rightArrowX, df.rightArrowY, s=100, marker='>', color='lightgreen', alpha=1, ax=ax)
downArrows = pitch.scatter(df.downArrowX, df.downArrowY, s=100, marker='v', color='lightgreen', alpha=1, ax=ax)
upArrows = pitch.scatter(df.upArrowX, df.upArrowY, s=100, marker='^', color='lightgreen', alpha=1, ax=ax)
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgx39.png)

How can I calculate the co-ordinates for the triangles more accurately given the original marker co-ordinates & marker size, so that they are placed evenly away at each point.

Or possibly any other solution to my problem.

Note: The pitch has co-ordinates 100x100, done in Jupyter Notebook. Thanks.

Comment: I would prefer a class to represent the 'marker' you desribed, also you should provide code that others can run.

Comment: `scatter` marker sizes are specified in display coordinates. You will notice that if you resize the figure, their size relative to the pitch changes. I would use the `RegularPolygon` class in `matplotlib.patches` for which the size (radius) is specified in data coordinates. You can then work out the relative positions through simple geometry rather than guesswork.

Comment: @PaulBrodersen I've managed to plot the octagons this way however because both the x and y axis for the pitch are 100x100, the octagons are stretched. The only solutions I've found are to change the axis so that they're equally distributed, however this is obviously not ideal. Do you have any idea how I could get them not to be stretched?

Comment: You might want to think about this in terms of the transforms Matplotlib uses. This is a couple layers deeper than beginning projects, but there's a good [https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html?highlight=transform+data+pixel+point](tutorial)  on it.